# cutycapt - anyone know if i can use this with a site using http authentication?

Tags: screen-capture

I am trying to capture a screen but am unable to do so because of a username/password pop-up. Is there any way that I can pass that in?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the credentials in the URL:

```
http://username:password@example.com/
```

Comment: tried it - did not work

Answer (score 0):

If you have "@" signs in user and/or password, you have to url-escape them (and other special characters). "`%40`" is i.e. the "`@`" sign.

Example:

```
user: ingo@baab.de
pass: foo@bar
```

will result in:

```
http://ingo%40baab.de:foo%40bar@example.com
```

Comment: Please don't post signatures or links to your site that are unrelated to the question or answer, as that could be considered spam. See [How not to be a spammer](https://superuser.com/help/promotion)